# Difference between Reading a characteristic and setting up notifications

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

Hi I am working on a Bluetooth low energy in my android app 
I am able to read the characteristics whenever I call my `readCharacter()` in app 
but I want to enable a notification such that when ever there is data available I can read. 
Currently I am using the method below.

```
private byte[] readCharacteristic(){
 if(!isReadEnabled){
        enableTXNotification();
        isReadEnabled = true;
    }

    byte[] arr = new byte[CHUCK_SIZE];
    BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
    if(RxService == null){
        broadcastUpdate(BLUETOOTH_EVENT_SERVICES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        return arr;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID);
    if(TxChar == null){
        broadcastUpdate(BLUETOOTH_EVENT_SERVICES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        return arr;
    }
    arr = TxChar.getValue();
    Log.d(TAG,Arrays.toString(arr));
    return arr;
}
```

And this is my `enableTXNotification()`:

```
private void enableTXNotification(){
    if (mBluetoothGatt == null) {
        broadcastUpdate(BLUETOOTH_EVENT_SERVICES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        return;
    }

    BluetoothGattService RxService = mBluetoothGatt.getService(RX_SERVICE_UUID);
    if (RxService == null) {
        broadcastUpdate(BLUETOOTH_EVENT_SERVICES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        return;
    }
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic TxChar = RxService.getCharacteristic(TX_CHAR_UUID);
    if (TxChar == null) {
        broadcastUpdate(BLUETOOTH_EVENT_SERVICES_NOT_SUPPORTED);
        return;
    }
    mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(TxChar,true);
    BluetoothGattDescriptor descriptor = TxChar.getDescriptor(CCCD);
    descriptor.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
    mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(descriptor);
}
```

#### So my question is what is the difference between Enabling notification and Reading characteristic?

#### How can I get notification whenever data is available

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is that notification is triggered from peripheral and read would be form central.
For peripheral where you want to save power you you can use "latency" feature.
Then notify may have lower latency and higher data rate than read.
That make even more sense if the peripheral creates data in randomly.